# Efficiently find unique elements in 2-dim array T[][] in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, unique, distinct-values

One solution to extract unique values would be to apply `Array[i].Distinct()` to each row and then form the list of all the unique elements from each row. Then we can repeat for this list `List.Distinct()`.

But is there more efficient way how to create `T[] UniqueValues` out of `T[][] Data`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var distinct = array.SelectMany(a => a).Distinct().ToArray();
```

This simply flattens the nested arrays into a sequence and calls `Distinct` to find the distinct elements. The call to `ToArray` may be somewhat inefficient since the length of the distinct sequence is not known in advance. This is unlikely to be a problem if there are only a small number of distinct elements.

If you have a large input array, it may be quicker to copy the elements copy the elements into a new array, perform a radix sort and then iterate over the sorted array while skipping equal elements.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a word of wisdom about efficiency of your method? Is there any faster way?

Comment: It makes one `HashSet` instead of N+1 `HashSet`s. So it's faster. It's better to use `ToList()` from `ToArray()` if you don't care about it.