# Find Unique line output of a 2 dimensional string array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, sorting

I have the following string;

```
string[,] test=
{
  {"0","0"},
  {"0","0"},
  {"0","0"},
  {"0","1"},
  {"5","0"},
};
```

I'd like to find a way to search the array for all lines that are unique.
So my desired output array would be.

```
string[,] output=
{
  {"0","0"},
  {"0","1"},
  {"5","0"},
};
```

Does anyone have any simple ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with linq just call `Distinct` to select only unique values, like this

```
var query = (from arr in test
             from value in arr
             select value).Distinct();
```

or you can try the following method, This simply flattens the nested arrays into a sequence and calls Distinct to find the distinct elements. source [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818046/efficiently-find-unique-elements-in-2-dim-array-t-in-c-sharp)

```
var distinct = test.SelectMany(a => a).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: This works for a one dimensional array, not a two dimensional array.
Error 19 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'string[*,*]'.  'SelectMany' not found.